# getRemoteDevice null object reference Error sending bluetooth string

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to send a string to a bluetooth device (HC-06), but I keep recieving the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                 Process: com.fiber.sliderapp, PID: 29808
>                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.fiber.sliderapp/com.fiber.sliderapp.ControleOnlineActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3450)
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3490)
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2749)
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
>                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
>                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
>                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference
>                     at com.fiber.sliderapp.ControleOnlineActivity.onResume(ControleOnlineActivity.java:60)
>                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1291)
>                     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6791)
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3427)
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3490) 
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2749) 
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490) 
>                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
>                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

The code I'm using:

```
    package com.fiber.sliderapp;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ControleOnlineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "bluetooth1";

    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;

    // SPP UUID service
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
    public static String address = "98:D3:31:70:0D:0C";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_controle_online);
    }

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
            try {
                final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
                return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
            }
        }
        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

        // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

        // Two things are needed to make a connection:
        //   A MAC address, which we got above.
        //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
        //     UUID for SPP.

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e1.getMessage() + ".");
        }

        // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
        // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "...Connection ok...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }

        // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

        try {
            outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

        if (outStream != null) {
            try {
                outStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }

        try     {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    private void checkBTState() {
        // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
        // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
        if(btAdapter==null) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
            } else {
                //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void errorExit(String title, String message){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    private void sendData(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

        Log.d(TAG, "...Send data: " + message + "...");

        try {
            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
            if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
                msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 35 in the java code";
            msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

            errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
        }
    }


    public void message_Hor_Esq(View v){
        EditText par;
        par = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_horizontal);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(par.getText().toString())) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Preencha uma velocidade", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            String msg = "C_H_E_" + par.getText().toString() + "/";
            sendData("1");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void message_Hor_Dir(View v){
        EditText par;
        par = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_horizontal);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(par.getText().toString())) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Preencha uma velocidade", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            String msg = "C_H_D_" + par.getText().toString() + "/";
            sendData("0");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


}
```

Anyone knows where is the problem?

Comment: Debug your code and spot the point at which it is failing, then include only the relevant code around there.

Comment: Looks like the problem is on this line: BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address); Can you check that the value of address is not null?

Comment: @Boris the value of address is not null, as defined at line: public static String address = "98:D3:31:70:0D:0C";

Comment: You are right. Then it must be btAdapter which is null.

Comment: @Boris That was the exactly the problem, I've forgot to initialize the btAdapter. Thanks a lot.